# Echo all values in php array as a sentence

Tags: php, arrays, echo

Is it possible to display an array as a sentence? So between each of the values there would be ", " except before the last value there would be " and ".

I have taken this little piece of code to use within an example:

```
<?php
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota"); 
echo "I like " . $cars[0] . ", " . $cars[1] . " and " . $cars[2] . ".";
?>
```

This works great for three values but I need it to work for between 1 and 15 values.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$carsCount = count($cars);

if ($carsCount == 1) {
    $sentence = $cars[0] . '.';
} else {
    $partial = array_slice($cars, 0, $carsCount-1);
    $sentence = implode(', ', $partial) . ' and ' . $cars[$carsCount-1];
}

echo $sentence;
```

Comment: Works great until there is only one value. Then it displays "and toyota".

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. Works brilliantly. Good karma too you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");

$sentence = '';
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
   if (count($array) == 1) {
      $sentence = $v;
      break;
   }
   else if ($k == count($array)-1) {
      $sentence .= 'and ' . $v;
   }
   else {
      $sentence .= $v . ', ';
   }
}

echo $sentence;
```

Above returns the following: Volvo, BMW, and Toyota

Answer (score 0):

**There is another way [shorter], [faster].**

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "Fiat");
if (count($cars) > 1) {
    $lastVal = array_pop($cars);
    echo implode(",", $cars)." and ".$lastVal;
} else {
    echo $cars[0];
}
```